# how to get selected text from uitextfield in iphone?

Tags: ios, iphone, textfield

I am working on Text to speech application in iPhone,

in which have a text field that takes input, i want user to select some portion of text from text field and my application will convert that selected text into speech.

my problem is how would i get the text that user has selected from text field?

Comment: @Anh: Gahhh, I didn't see the OP's answer before rejecting your edit. Turns out he **was** using a text view, but mistakenly wrote text field in the question. Sorry about that!

Answer (score 31, accepted):

#### `-[UITextField selectedText]`

Although [`UITextField`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/UIKit/Reference/UITextField_Class/Reference/UITextField.html) doesn't have a `selectedText` method, it conforms to the [`UITextInput` protocol](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/DOCUMENTATION/UIKit/Reference/UITextInput_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/intf/UITextInput). So, you can use the required properties & methods of the `UITextInput` protocol to determine the `selectedText` of a `UITextField *textField` (or any object that conforms to the `UITextInput` protocol, such as a [`UITextView`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/UIKit/Reference/UITextView_Class/Reference/UITextView.html)).

```
NSString *selectedText = [textField textInRange:textField.selectedTextRange];
NSLog(@"selectedText: %@", selectedText);
```

As an aside, you can also use the required properties & methods of the `UITextInput` to calculate the `selectedRange` of a `UITextField *textField`.

```
UITextRange *selectedTextRange = textField.selectedTextRange;
NSUInteger location = [textField offsetFromPosition:textField.beginningOfDocument
                                         toPosition:selectedTextRange.start];
NSUInteger length = [textField offsetFromPosition:selectedTextRange.start
                                       toPosition:selectedTextRange.end];
NSRange selectedRange = NSMakeRange(location, length);
NSLog(@"selectedRange: %@", NSStringFromRange(selectedRange));
```

#### `-[UITextFieldDelegate textFieldDidChangeSelection:]`

Although, `UITextFieldDelegate` doesn't declare a `textFieldDidChangeSelection:` delegate method like [`-[UITextViewDelegate textViewDidChangeSelection:]`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/DOCUMENTATION/UIKit/Reference/UITextViewDelegate_Protocol/Reference/UITextViewDelegate.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/UITextViewDelegate/textViewDidChangeSelection%3a), you can still hook into when the selection of a `UITextField` has changed. To do so, subclass `UITextField` and use method swizzling to add your own code to the `textField.inputDelegate`'s native implementation of [`-[UITextInputDelegate selectionDidChange:]`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/DOCUMENTATION/UIKit/Reference/UITextInputDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/UITextInputDelegate/selectionDidChange%3a).

```
// MyTextField.h

#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface MyTextField : UITextField

@end


// MyTextField.m

#import <objc/runtime.h>
#import "MyTextField.h"

UIKIT_STATIC_INLINE void mySelectionDidChange(id self, SEL _cmd, id<UITextInput> textInput);

@implementation MyTextField {
    BOOL swizzled;
}

#pragma mark - UIResponder

// Swizzle here because self.inputDelegate is set after becomeFirstResponder gets called.
- (BOOL)becomeFirstResponder {
    if ([super becomeFirstResponder]) {
        [self swizzleSelectionDidChange:YES];
        return YES;
    } else {
        return NO;
    }
}

// Unswizzle here because self.inputDelegate may become the inputDelegate for another UITextField.
- (BOOL)resignFirstResponder {
    if ([super resignFirstResponder]) {
        [self swizzleSelectionDidChange:NO];
        return YES;
    } else {
        return NO;
    }
}

#pragma mark - Swizzle -[UITextInput selectionDidChange:]

// Swizzle selectionDidChange: to "do whatever you want" when the text field's selection has changed.
// Only call this method on the main (UI) thread because it may not be thread safe.
- (void)swizzleSelectionDidChange:(BOOL)swizzle {
    if (swizzle == swizzled || ![self respondsToSelector:@selector(inputDelegate)]) return; // 4.3

    Class inputDelegateClass = object_getClass(self.inputDelegate);
    SEL mySelector = @selector(mySelectionDidChange:);
    class_addMethod(inputDelegateClass, mySelector, (IMP)mySelectionDidChange, "v@:@");
    Method myMethod    = class_getInstanceMethod(inputDelegateClass, mySelector);
    Method uiKitMethod = class_getInstanceMethod(inputDelegateClass, @selector(selectionDidChange:));
    method_exchangeImplementations(uiKitMethod, myMethod);
    swizzled = swizzle;
    // NSLog(@"swizzled? %i", method_getImplementation(uiKitMethod) == (IMP)venmo_selectionDidChange);
}

@end

UIKIT_STATIC_INLINE void mySelectionDidChange(id self, SEL _cmd, id<UITextInput> textInput) {
    // Call the native implementation of selectionDidChange:.
    [self performSelector:@selector(mySelectionDidChange:) withObject:textInput];

    // "Do whatever you want" with the selectedText below.
    NSString *selectedText = [textInput textInRange:textInput.selectedTextRange];
    NSLog(@"selectedText: %@", selectedText);        
}
```

Answer (score 6):

I did solve my query as follow :

I implement UITextView's delegate and implement following method

```
- (void)textViewDidChangeSelection:(UITextView *)textView {
    NSRange r = textView.selectedRange;
    NSLog(@"Start from : %d",r.location); //starting selection in text selection
    NSLog(@"To : %d",r.length); // end position in text selection
    NSLog([tv.text substringWithRange:NSMakeRange(r.location, r.length)]); //tv is my text view
}
```

That's it!

Comment: If you were using a text view, don't say in your question that you were using a text field. They're two completely different things.

Comment: @BoltClock: Hi Sorry for that. but eventually i found code for with textview that's why i change my mind and implement it with textview. sorry for that dear.

Answer (score 2):

## Swift

In Swift, getting the selected text from a `UITextField` is done like this:

```
if let textRange = myTextField.selectedTextRange {

    let selectedText = myTextField.textInRange(textRange)
    
}
```

where `textRange` is a `UITextRange` that is used to get the actual selected text.

Answer (score 1):

A similar topic is discussed here: [Can I select a specific block of text in a UITextField?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3277538/can-i-select-a-specific-block-of-text-in-a-uitextfield)

AFAIK there is no event if text is selected. However, you could setup an NSTimer to watch your textfield and check the `_selectedRange`. If it changes, go fire up your text-to-speech code.

**EDIT**: I was wrong about the selection. UITextField cannot do what you want to achieve. But if you use `UITextView` instead, you can implement its UITextViewDelegate and override

```
- (void)textViewDidChangeSelection:(UITextView *)textView
```

In there, you can use the `selectedRange` poperty to get the selection. See this reference for details:

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITextView_Class/Reference/UITextView.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006898-CH3-SW13

Comment: i saw what you suggest, but not got the point how that solves my problem? will you please elaborate your suggestion please..!

Answer (score 0):

UITextField don't have delegate to get the selection range change. We can use KVO to observe `selectedTextRange` property of `UITextfield`.

```
    [textField addObserver:self forKeyPath:@"selectedTextRange" options:NSKeyValueObservingOptionNew context:NULL];
```

Or create `UITextField` subclass and override `setSelectedTextRange` method.