# Get character before cursor in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, uitextfield

Yesterday I was working on [getting and setting the cursor position in a `UITextField`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34922332/3681880). Now I am trying to get the character just before the cursor position. So in the following example, I would want to return an "e".

[image]

```
func characterBeforeCursor() -> String
```

Notes

- I didn't see any other SO questions that were the same of this, but maybe I missed them.
- I wrote this question first and when I find an answer I will post both the question and the answer at the same time. Of course, better answers are welcomed.
- I said "character" but `String` is fine.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

If the cursor is showing and the position one place before it is valid, then get that text. Thanks to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11354330/3681880) for some hints.

```
func characterBeforeCursor() -> String? {

    // get the cursor position
    if let cursorRange = textField.selectedTextRange {

        // get the position one character before the cursor start position
        if let newPosition = textField.position(from: cursorRange.start, offset: -1) {

            let range = textField.textRange(from: newPosition, to: cursorRange.start)
            return textField.text(in: range!)
        }
    }
    return nil
}
```

[image]

The result of

```
if let text = characterBeforeCursor() {
    print(text)
}
```

is "e", as per your example.

Comment: Tested: This not work for emojis.

Answer (score 0):

**You can also use this:**

```
NSInteger endOffset = [textfld offsetFromPosition:textfld.beginningOfDocument toPosition:range1.end];

NSRange offsetRange = NSMakeRange(endOffset-1, 1);

NSString *str1 = [textfld.text substringWithRange:offsetRange];
NSLog(@"str1= %@",str1);
```

Comment: This might work in Objective-C, but Integers don't work for text ranges in Swift.

Answer (score 0):

**In swift you can use**

```
let range1 : UITextRange = textField.selectedTextRange!

let  endoffset : NSInteger = textField.offsetFromPosition(textField.beginningOfDocument, toPosition: range1.end)

let offsetRange : NSRange = NSMakeRange(endoffset-1, 1)

let index: String.Index = (textField.text?.startIndex.advancedBy(offsetRange.location))!

let str1 : String = (textField.text?.substringFromIndex(index))!

let index1 : String.Index = str1.startIndex.advancedBy(1)

let str2: String = str1.substringToIndex(index1)

print(str2)
```

Comment: This will work in some situations but crashes in other situations. For example, try entering a string of emoji and see what the result is. (By the way, you can format your code by indenting every line 4 spaces.)