# DidchangeSelection method for textfield in swift

Tags: swift, delegates, textfield

I want to call a method when cursor is moved in textfield. I found a delegate for textview "textviewdidchangeselection" . I want to write this method for textfield with swift. 
I found this method in objective-c but I cant undrestand it .

[objective-c code](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11354330/5452535)

Comment: There is no one to answer my question ??? :(