# Change cursor in UITextField when set new text

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, uitextfield

I discovery one thing. If i set yes to function

```
- textField:shouldChangeCharactersInRange:replacementString:
```

The cursor stay in the same place I type, like ("|" = cursor)

```
"|"     => Empty , type a
"a|"    => type b
"ab|"   => change cursor
"a|b"   => type c
"ac|b"  => type d
"acd|b" => change cursor
"ac|db" => type backspace
"a|db"  => type backspace again
"|db"   => *result*
```

But, if I have to change the text, like put a `"-"` in penultimate character, I do the logic thing and set the text with:

```
  [textField setText:newText];
```

But the sample above will be in this way:

```
"|"      => Empty , type a
"a|"     => type b               (put character "-" automatic)
"a-b|"   => user change cursor
"a|-b"   => type c    
"ac-b|"  => type d               ## the cursor is in end ##
"acb-d|" => change cursor        ## "d" is in wrong place, the user have to  
                                 ## change cursor to reproduce the result above
"ac|b-d" => type backspace
"ab-d|"  => type backspace again   ## the cursor is in end again ##
"a-b|"   => *result*               ## I want delete "a" but it delete "d"
```

How can I set the cursor to the result is the same `"|d-b"` like in the first sample? Or better question: **How change the text and the cursor in a UITextField?**

Comment: possible duplicate of [Can I select a specific block of text in a UITextField?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3277538/can-i-select-a-specific-block-of-text-in-a-uitextfield)

Comment: I think is not duplicate, is a different thing.

Comment: Selection and cursor position are one and the same. So I think the answers to that question also apply here.

Comment: Did you solve this problem? I encounter the same problem, and the post provided by jtbandes doesn't solve my problem under iPad with iOS 5.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the solution. I can't choice the cursor place, but it do what I want. You have to use the function of protocol **UIKeyInput** There are 2 good function:

```
- (void)insertText:(NSString *)text;
- (void)deleteBackward;
```

Than, redoing my test case, I have:

```
"|"      => Empty , type a
"a|"     => type b               (put character "-" automatic)
"a-b|"   => user change cursor
"a|-b"   => type c               (enter the character with a [textField insertText:@"c"]
"ac|-b"  => type d               (the same thing: [textField insertText:@"d"])
"acd|-b" => change cursor
"ac|d-b" => type backspace       (use a [textField deleteBackward])
"a|d-b"  => type backspace
"|d-b"   => *result*             (Work!!!)
```

You can't change the cursor, but for normal typing it solve the problems!.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try using the [UITextInput](http://developer.apple.com/library/iOS/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITextInput_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/intf/UITextInput) protocol for gathering cursor position information?

Comment: No. And the UITextField don't use it. But, I get the position of the cursor with `shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range`. (it give-me the size and place that was changed)

Comment: Then maybe try UIKeyInput's ```insertText:``` to insert text at the cursor position, instead of calling ```setText:``` to replace the whole text?

Comment: Man, I thing I am almost solving this problem. But how I use the UIKeyInput protocol? I try this `UITextField <UIKeyInput> *textField;` but I can't call the UIKeyInput functions and it is never called.