# How to move cursor position forward for a particular length?

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch

I have a `UITextField`, how can I change the cursor position dynamically based of some condition to a particular length?

Answer (score 1):

Use `textview.selectedRange`.

```
NSRange selection = [textview.text rangeOfString:@"SomeText" options:NSCaseInsensitiveSearch];
if( selection.location != NSNotFound ){
    textview.selectedRange =  selection;
    textview.selectedRange = NSMakeRange(selection.location, 0);
}
```

It may helps you

Answer (score 0):

Use this link maybe it will help you solve your issue. Hope it is of use !! :)

[Change cursor in UITextField when set new text](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7196032/change-cursor-in-uitextfield-when-set-new-text)

and also Finding the cursor position in a UITextField

```
// Get the selected text range
    UITextRange *selectedRange = [self selectedTextRange];

    // Calculate the existing position, relative to the end of the field (will be a - number)
    int pos = [self offsetFromPosition:self.endOfDocument toPosition:selectedRange.start];

    // Change the text
    self.text = lastValidated; 

    // Work out the position based by offsetting the end of the field to the same
    // offset we had before editing
    UITextPosition *newPos = [self positionFromPosition:self.endOfDocument offset:pos];

    // Reselect the range, to move the cursor to that position
    self.selectedTextRange = [self textRangeFromPosition:newPos toPosition:newPos];
```

Happy coding....

Comment: I don't want to change the cursor, I want to change the cursor position.

Comment: go to this link and try to code in your project http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7196032/change-cursor-in-uitextfield-when-set-new-text