# UITextField SigAbrts on selectedTextRange

Tags: objective-c, uitextfield, selectedtext

I'm trying to find and delete the selected text in a text field, but it SIGABRTs every time.  I keep getting an NSInvalidArgumentException when I try to retrieve the selectedTextRange.  In fact I tested it and every function having to do with the selected text seems to break the app.

```
[mTextField selectedTextRange];
```

Even that line of code itself is an unrecognized selector for some reason.  I've double checked that I'm not using garbage data or anything, I'm able to get the text first and then getting the selected text afterwards breaks it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`selectedTextRange` can only use on iOS5+.

Comment: Yea we figured that out a little while after, it seems pretty silly that this would be added so late in the features.

Answer (score 1):

Since you tagged your question with nstextfield, I assume you're using an [`NSTextField`](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSTextField_Class/Reference/Reference.html) (Mac OS X) rather than a `UITextField` (iOS).  The problem is `NSTextField` doesn't support the `selectedTextRange` message.  (`UITextField` does support it.)  I don't see any way to get the selected range from an `NSTextField`.

If you switch to using [`NSTextView`](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSTextView_Class/Reference/Reference.html), you can send it the `selectedRanges` message.

Comment: Sorry that was a typo, it's actually a UITextField.  Getting my prefixes mixed up over this.

Answer (score 1):

I seriously dont think that you can achieve that by using UITextField.

However I think u can sort of do that by implementing UITextViewDelegate. You can use selectedRange property in this method.

> ```
> - (void)textViewDidChangeSelection:(UITextView *)textView
> ```

By the way your question might have something to do with this question:

[Can I select a specific block of text in a UITextField?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3277538/can-i-select-a-specific-block-of-text-in-a-uitextfield)

Do check it out..