# UITextInput setMarkedText:selectedRange not working? (Can't be!)

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uitextview, uitextinput

I want to set the marked text programmatically and since iOS5 UITextView and UITextField conform to UITextInput this should be possible but for some reason I always get the `markedText` to be nil. :(
What am I missing here?

This is what I've tried without success:

(While the textview is firstResponder)

**1.- When the text view contains no text:**

text: "", selectedRange : {0,0}, markedText: nil.

```
[_textView setMarkedText:@"月" selectedRange:NSMakeRange(0, 1)];
```

**Result:**
text : "", selectedRange: {0,0}, markedText: nil. (Nothing changed)

**2.- When the text view contains text + some marked text:**

text : "AAA", selectedRange = {0,3}, marked text at the end : "太陽"
then I do:

```
[_textView setMarkedText:@"地" selectedRange:NSMakeRange(0,3)];
```

**Result :**
text :"AAA", selectedRange: {0,3}, markedText: nil; (the marked text became nil)

In both cases is like `setMarkedText:selectedRange:` would be setting the current marked text (if some) to nil.

Any help would be highly appreciated :)

### UPDATE

Since the concept of marked text seems to be unclear, here is an explanation:

In multi stage input languages (e.g. Japanese) you can input regular text (like english) or input marked text (like japanese).

Here I wrote regular text : `regular text` then I wrote marked text `つ`
and then I wrote marked text `き` so it was appended becoming `つき`.

Marked text (text in the blue box) represents a transitional or intermediate input stage because it can become into other characters/words called candidates. Candidates are shown in the big box.

This screenshot was taken when using a bluetooth keyboard in the iPad but you will get similar results when using the software keyboard when writing japanese for example.

Before writing `つ` the textview was:

```
textView.text : "regular text"
textView.selectedRange : {12,0}
textView.markedText:nil
```

Then I wrote `つ` and the text view became:

```
textView.text : "regular textつ"
textView.selectedRange : {13,0}
textView.markedText: "つ"
```

Then I wrote `き` and the text view became:

```
textView.text : "regular textつき"
textView.selectedRange : {14,0}
textView.markedText: "つき"
```

Which is the current state of the text view.

I want to be able to set the marked text programatically :)

Is this possible? -- According to UITextInput docs it is.

[image]

Comment: To narrow the issue down, you could try using only Western characters and see if you still have the same issue.

Comment: Tried it with alphabet too .... The result is the same :(

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I have a conceptual problem with your code here. I may just be overlooking some small thing, but I think you just have a simple error in your programming.

1) When the text view contains no text: `text: "", selectedRange : {0,0}, markedText: nil`:

```
[_textView setMarkedText:@"月" selectedRange:NSMakeRange(0, 1)];

Result: text: "", selectedRange: {0,0}, markedText: nil.
```

(Nothing changed)

2) When the text view contains text + some marked text: `text: "AAA"`, `selectedRange: {0,3}`, `markedText` at the end: "太陽" then I do:

```
[_textView setMarkedText:@"地" selectedRangeNSMakeRange(0,3)];

Result: text: "AAA", selectedRange: {0,3}, markedText: nil;
```

(the marked text became nil)

**I just fixed your problem** in the code that I ran in Xcode. It ran flawlessly and changed the marked text when I clicked three different buttons. When there was no marked text, the text was appended and marked.

`text` is the name of a `UITextView`:

```
-(IBAction)first
{
    [text setMarkedText:@"test" selectedRange:NSMakeRange(0, 4)];
}
-(IBAction)second
{
    [text setMarkedText:@"woo" selectedRange:NSMakeRange(0,4)];
}
```

Here I clicked "First"
[image: When First is Clicked]

Here I clicked "Second"
[image: When Second is Clicked]

I hope this helps you and is deserving of the bounty.

Comment: Sorry about the block quote being formatted as code. The engine wouldn't allow me to leave it as a block quote because it included code.

Comment: Thank you David. About the **first**, **second**, and **third** problem: method `[textView setMarkedText:@"月" selectedRange:range` will NOT search `月` and then *mark* , Instead it is supposed to input `月` as *marketText* or replace the current markedText if there is one.

Comment: About the **fourth** problem, that is just an typo, in my program I wrote is correctly. I just corrected it here.

Comment: Hmm, okay I see what you are saying, let me try it real quick in xcode and see what I can do.

Comment: Indeed , this time it worked. Thank you so much for your answer. I guess I will have to report this as a bug. `setMarkedText:selectedRange` work **only** when the textview is not the first responder, making the API almost useless because it is intended to be used while editing the text. Thank David again.

Comment: I'm glad this worked for you. You must be right because this worked when I hadn't made a single edit to the textview. I just slammed together a new project in 5 minutes and it worked perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

Did you add the UITextField to the view before setting it's contents (and marking the text)?

Comment: According to this topic: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3277538/can-i-select-a-specific-block-of-text-in-a-uitextfield you should force the textfield, to be the first responder.

Comment: The text view is first responder at that moment. BTW, I answered that question :)