# UITextView not saving markedTextStyle (UITextInput protocol)

Tags: ios, uitextview, uitextinput

Marking text in a UITextView, but for some reason it's refusing to accept anything I give it with setMarkedTextStyle. -markedTextStyle always returns nil, and the marked text always looks the same (blue background and maintains text color).

```
[_taggedUsersView setMarkedTextStyle:@{UITextInputTextColorKey: [UIColor whiteColor], UITextInputTextBackgroundColorKey: [UIColor tranceLinkBlue], UITextInputTextFontKey: [UIFont fontWithName:@"HelveticaNeue-Medium" size:14.0]}];
```

Tried doing this both when I create the textview, right before marking text and right after. But it still maintains the default style, and returns nil for the style.

Comment: Long shot, but have you tried self.taggedUsersView?

Comment: If you're running iOS 8, that can be a problem as it is now deprecated: `Deprecated in iOS 8.0.`

Comment: What is deprecated? Both markedTextStyle and setMarkedTextRange isn't deprecated in the iOS 8 docs I'm looking at now.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8066628/uitextinput-setmarkedtextselectedrange-not-working-cant-be?rq=1

Comment: Not the same issue Kumar. My markedText is not nil, just the style.

Answer (score 2):

After a lot of testing the only thing I can say is that it is a bug in the SDK. Setting `markedTextStyle` property has no effect and getter returns always nil.

This comes against what we can read in documentation:

> **`markedTextStyle`**
>
> A dictionary of attributes that describes how marked
>   text should be drawn.

I reported it to Apple as a bug (Bug ID - `17914881`).

Comment: UITextField is equally affected by this bug. I've reported rdar://30208223 / http://openradar.appspot.com/30208223). Did you ever get a response to your report?

Comment: Still not fixed I believe 

Nothing happens when I set it on iOS 13

Answer (score 0):

I think you want to use attributed text property instead of markedtextstyle (if I understand your question correctly)

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/uitextview_class/Reference/UITextView.html

[How can I set the color and alignment of attributed text in a UITextView in iOS 7?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19339879/how-can-i-set-the-color-and-alignment-of-attributed-text-in-a-uitextview-in-ios)

Comment: Actually the marked text style is separate from this. I'm already using attributed text in the textview, but the marked style is independent of that.

Answer (score 0):

Do you want to change the `selectedText` or the `markedText` property?

The later will only for Chinese/Japanese writing so maybe you should try modifying `highlightedTextColor` instead.