# How to get all attributes for -[NSString sizeWithAttributes:]

Tags: ios, nsstring, uitextview, nsattributedstring, sizewithfont

So that I can calculate the `intrinsicContentSize` of a `UITextView`, I'm wondering how to get all the attributes of an attributed string so I can pass them to `-[NSString sizeWithAttributes:]`?

Answer (score -1):

Dude, am I missing something here? Why not just use [`-[NSAttributedString size]`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/NSAttributedString_UIKit_Additions/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSAttributedString/size)? Also, check out [UITextView NSAttributedString Size](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14545096/uitextview-nsattributedstring-size).

Comment: I think just `size` is kinda useless. in 99% of the cases you want to supply a constraint, no? so: I'd use `boundingRectWithSize:options:context:`

Comment: + op has a string. not an attributed string

Answer (score -2):

You can get the attributes for the textview by getting it's attributedString and then getting the attributes of it:

`NSDictionary *attrs = aTextView.attributedText.attributes`

---

ELSE you can get the font of the textview. (if it isn't richtext, thats enough)

`NSDictionary *attrs = @{NSFontAttributeName: aTextView.font };`

---

BUT if you want the size just call `boundingRectWithSize:options:context:` on the attributedString you have.