# Highlight Text in iPhone

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, text, highlight

I am developing an app in which I need to give the user the user to highlight some of the text in the given paragraph. The user will select some text and then highlight it. The functionality is same as Adobe reader ios app or iBooks.
After lot of brainstorming, I found UIWebView that could solve my problem. But it   then create other critical problem regarding other app requirements. So I had to left that idea.

I still don't have any idea that how to proceed.

Comment: wt u want ?? explain clearly..

Comment: Adobe reader type application.

Comment: are you going to be working with only PDF files?

Comment: no, the input is simple text.

Comment: isn't UITextView enough ? or do you need different fonts and formats?

Comment: I think no one is getting your question. better if u give image of what u want.

Comment: I would take a look [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/3278460/312312)

Answer (score 0):

Try [this sample code](https://github.com/AliSoftware/OHAttributedLabel). I think it should help you with this question.